# Logstash-output-mongodb depends on older version

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

everytime i try to install the mongo output plugin, it always show this error: Plugin version conflict, aborting
ERROR: Installation Aborted, message: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mongo":
In Gemfile:
logstash-output-mongodb (= 3.1.3) java depends on
mongo (~> 2.0.6) java
Could not find gem 'mongo (~> 2.0.6) java', which is required by gem 'logstash-output-mongodb (= 3.1.3) java', in any of the sources.
i tried to update the bundle but it keeps using the mongo 2.0.6.... what can i do please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually the problem solved just by uninstall the logstash and install it again